# Cannot create new documents inside Modern Document Sets in SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, document-set

I've just created a customised document set with about 6 metadata fields; and in the Modern view the option to create a document from the Command Bar does not exist.

Has anyone else had this problem? For the moment I've changed the view back to classic.

[image: Command Bar with no option to create new]

Answer (score 0):

I can create new documents inside Modern Document Sets in SP Online:

[image]

How did you created a customised document set with about 6 metadata fields?

Does the issue exists in other library? Try to create a new library and compare the results.

Open your library in another browser and compare the results.

Comment: Is there anything update?